# How to send sessionID from soapui as a request

Tags: web-services, jax-ws, apache-axis, soapui

I am testing a webservice method which accepts session-id as a parameter.

While testing the same method via SoapUI with a dummy sessionID-Parameter, the server is rejecting the request as it is expecting proper session-id.

How can I solve this? Is there any way where SoapUI can bind the session-id before sending the request?

Please advice me. Thanks

Below is the sample-request which is triggered from SOAP-UI:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://services.local.com">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ser:getMultiple>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ser:sessionId>1000AJHEFG0987</ser:sessionId>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ser:lessonId>95101</ser:lessonId>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ser:quantity>1</ser:quantity>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ser:impressionRow>1</ser:impressionRow>
      </ser:getParametersMultiple>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: So what constitutes a valid sessionId?

Comment: Not sure Chris. They check the incoming session ID in the own way. But one thing is sure, if we send a dummy-session-ID the service is failing. So need to check how to capture the session-id and then send it in request from soap-ui

Comment: For our web services we have a separate login or authentication method which creates and returns the new session id. Are there any other methods on the interface you are calling?

Comment: We have no such method in our service. As in reality, the login will have from flash side and session-id will come in from flash scripts. But here am checking the services using soap-ui

Comment: Ok... so how does the flash script retrieve a session id? Where lies the logic of producing a session id? Is it possible to extract that logic? I don't know anything about flash scripts, but is the logic for sessions in that script?

Comment: There must be some logic, they get the session-id from the browser-cookie I think !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution,

- Design your login method which will accept certain inputs and will
  return the sessionID as a string
- Hit that login method from SOAP-UI and you will get the sessionID in
  your response
- Use "Property Transfer" option in soap-ui and transfer the received
  sessionID to all other requests

Helpful Link :  [soapui.org/Functional-Testing/transferring-property-values.h‌​tml](http://%20soapui.org/Functional-Testing/transferring-property-values.h%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Btml)

Simple !! :)

Comment: Where is this Property Transfer option?

Comment: Please google for it . This link might be useful to you http://www.soapui.org/Functional-Testing/transferring-property-values.html

Answer (score 1):

Let's say, if you get sessionid in first request's response, and the next request should go here `http://{{original endpoint}}/{{SESSION_ID}})`, this definitely works:

1. go to request (not the test request inside test case) where session id should be put into
2. add a parameter on 'request' tab
3. `name=sessionid`, `style=template`, `level=resource`. now it is empty in all related test requests
4. go to test request, 'request' tab
5. put the path to sessionid value from previous request into 'value' field of sessionid parameter. for example, it is like `${users#Response#$.session_id}` where 'users' is the name of endpoint resource, 'session_id' is the name of parameter inside response